# Can php be installed on a windows server?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008, php

Can php be installed on a windows server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Get the web platform installer.

http://www.iis.net/download on the left (Web PI).

It is like a package manager for IIS.

On IIS.NET you also ind a lot of nice add ons for PHP -fastcgi etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, PHP most certainly can be installed on Windows Server. You can choose to install the FastCGI or ISAPI modules in IIS, or alternatively you can install another web server package within windows, such as Apache.